# Live wallpaper and app at the same time

Tags: android

I have two separate apps on the market one a graphic game and another a wallpaper based on the same logic. I think it would give more incentive to users to buy the application if it could be combined with the wallpaper into one single package.

Is this possible, and any suggestion how to set up the AndroidManifest?

Comment: Hm, just add the wallpapers <service> declaration with the correct intent filter for the "android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" action (& configuration activity if so required) into your games manifest and you can bundle a wallpaper with just about any app.

Comment: Yeap, it is working! Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can reward you... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the wallpapers `<service>` declaration with the correct intent filter for the "`android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService`" action (& configuration activity if so required) into your games manifest and you can bundle a wallpaper with just about any app.